# The union of $(3,6) \cup (6,9]$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> $(3,6) \cup (6,9]$

I got $[4,5,7,8,9]$, which is missing an element in the interval.  I'm supposed to take the union and find the interior, boundary points, and accumulation points, but not sure how to do that when it's not a complete interval... unless my union is incorrect.

Hints on how I can do that on the above union?

Comment: Hint: those *real* intervals are continuous; not containing only integers.

Comment: I think these are intervals in the reals, so the union is all of the interval $(3,9]$ except for $6$. A tiny hole.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure of the notation - especially since I need to find the interior, boundary and accumulation points.

Comment: What set are you working in? If it's the integers, then the union is $\{4,5,7,8,9\}.$ (Notice the difference between that and your answer?) However, I suspect it is instead supposed to be the real numbers, in which case the union cannot be "simplified" any further, and this is simply an exercise in applying the three definitions in question. Do you know definitions for the three terms?

Comment: @CameronBuie that is what I figured, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Comment: So...what *is* the interior of a set defined to be?  Something about open sets and containment?  What is the interior of an interval $[a,b]$?  Of an interval $(a,b)$?  Of a union of two intervals?  How about boundaries?

Comment: @JMoravitz the interior of an interval $[a,b]$ is $(a,b)$ and the boundary is $\{a,b\}$, an open interval interior is $(a,b)$ and the boundary is $\{a,b\}$, but what I'm working with isn't a continuous interval...

Comment: You skipped the first question I asked to try to get you to think.  The interior of a set is the largest open set which is contained entirely within the set.  The result for intervals is as you say.  Now, what is the largest open set which is a subset of $(3,6)\cup (6,9]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $(3;6)\cup(6;9] ~\equiv~ (3;9]\setminus \{6\}$ .  That is, every point on the real interval between 3 and 9; including 9 but excluding both 3 and 6.

You should  be able to find the accumulation (limit) points, boundary points, and interior points of this from their definitions.